# Doesn't know about keyword 'this' in CAPL programming

Tags: capl

I am new to CAPL programming. I didn't understand what is the use of `this` keyword. Any body please explain?

Comment: Please do a web search. Requests for tutorials are off-topic here. You may want to take the  [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is basically a pointer, addressing the Simulation event, and its scope is within only that event.
You have no obligation to use it, but it does make life a lot simpler.
For Example:

```
        on envVar Env_DTC_ReadSnapshotButton
        {
           if(getValue(this))             
            {
              UpdateSnapshotResultsPanel();
            }
        }
```

you can replace `getValue( this )` with `getValue ( Env_DTC_ReadSnapshotButton )`.
The application of `this` is the same for all other similar simulation events like `on message`. The decision is yours, choose the one which you feel is simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `this` works like in many programming languages to indicate a class or struct inside the same class or struct.

For instance, let us say you have a message yourMessage, then:

```
on message yourMessage
{
    output(this)         // this == yourMessage in the context we are using.
}
```

Please remember you can always hit F1 in the CAPL browser when the caret is over a function to bring up help and references on said function.